# How to convert Array[String] into proper schema?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a weird issue while trying to dinamically convert the fields from a `RDD[Array[String]]` to the proper values specified in a schema for the conversion to a Spark SQL `DataFrame`.

I have a `RDD[Array[String]]` and a `StructType` called `schema` which specifies the types for the serveral fields. What I have done so far is:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    inputLines.map( rowValues => 
                          RowFactory.create(rowValues.zip(schema.toSeq)
                                                     .map{ case (value, struct) => 
                                                  struct.dataType match {
                                                    case BinaryType => value.toCharArray().map(ch => ch.toByte)
                                                    case ByteType => value.toByte
                                                    case BooleanType => value.toBoolean
                                                    case DoubleType => value.toDouble
                                                    case FloatType => value.toFloat
                                                    case ShortType => value.toShort
                                                    case DateType => value
                                                    case IntegerType => value.toInt
                                                    case LongType => value.toLong
                                                    case _ => value
                                                  }
                                               })), schema)
```

but I'm getting this Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to convert value [Ljava.lang.Object;@6e9ffad1 (class of class [Ljava.lang.Object;}) with the type of IntegerType to JSON
```

when calling the `toJSON` method...

Do you have any idea about the reason why this is happening and what could I do to fix it?

As asked, here we have an example:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("id",IntegerType),StructField("val",StringType)))
val inputLines=sc.parallelize(
      Array("1","This is a line for testing"), 
      Array("2","The second line"))
```

Comment: a sample input (`schema`, `inputLines`) would be helpful.

Comment: I get an exception with `val inputLines=sc.parallelize(Array("1","This is a line for testing"), Array("2","The second line"))` -- I think it should be: `val inputLines=sc.parallelize(Array(("1","This is a line for testing"), ("2","The second line")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `Array` as the only parameter to `RowFactory.create`.

If you see its method signature:

```
public static Row create(Object ... values)
```

it expects a `varargs` list.

So you just need to convert the array to varargs list, using `:_*` syntax.

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(inputLines.map( rowValues => 
   Row(              // RowFactory.create is java api, use Row.apply instead
      rowValues.zip(schema.toSeq)
                .map{ case (value, struct) => struct.dataType match {
                   case BinaryType => value.toCharArray().map(ch => ch.toByte)
                   case ByteType => value.toByte
                   case BooleanType => value.toBoolean
                   case DoubleType => value.toDouble
                   case FloatType => value.toFloat
                   case ShortType => value.toShort
                   case DateType => value
                   case IntegerType => value.toInt
                   case LongType => value.toLong
                   case _ => value
                   }
                 } : _*            // <-- make varargs here
   )),
   schema)
```

In code above, i have replaced RowFactory.create with Row.apply and passed argument as varargs.

Alternatively, use `Row.fromSeq` method.

Refactoring a bit:

```
def convertTypes(value: String, struct: StructField): Any = struct.dataType match {
  case BinaryType => value.toCharArray().map(ch => ch.toByte)
  case ByteType => value.toByte
  case BooleanType => value.toBoolean
  case DoubleType => value.toDouble
  case FloatType => value.toFloat
  case ShortType => value.toShort
  case DateType => value
  case IntegerType => value.toInt
  case LongType => value.toLong
  case _ => value
}

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("id",IntegerType),
                            StructField("val",StringType)))

val inputLines = sc.parallelize(Array(Array("1","This is a line for testing"), 
                                      Array("2","The second line")))

val rowRdd = inputLines.map{ array => 
  Row.fromSeq(array.zip(schema.toSeq)
                   .map{ case (value, struct) => 
                           convertTypes(value, struct) })
}

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema)

df.toJSON.collect 
// Array({"id":1,"val":"This is a line for testing"},
//       {"id":2,"val":"The second line"})
```